# Click TextView from one activity to show text in another activity

Tags: android

I am making a quotes app, and I have created an activity named Einstein.java where I have about 50 textviews with quotes. I want to make the quotes clickable so they pop up in another activity (QuotesCLick.java )single quotes at a time. This is my code:

Einstein.java:

```
public class Einstein extends Activity {
private RandomQuotes mRandomQuotes = new RandomQuotes();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.einstein);
}

public String getQuotes(){

    String quote = "";
    return quote;
 }
 }
```

QuotesClick.java:

```
public class QuoteClick extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
private Einstein mEinstein = new Einstein();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quote_click);
} 

final TextView quotesView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
TextView getQuote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String quote = mEinstein.getQuotes();

    quotesView.setText(quote);
    }
    }
```

Comment: where you set onclicklistener ??

Comment: "50 textviews with quotes" > why not a listview/extendable listview ?

Comment: `new Einstein();` you are not allowed to do that. `Einstein` is an activity, it is created by the system.

Comment: please put your full code of both class or show your xml so, i can identify what you are using to show quoutes .

Comment: 50 quotes, you can make it through with Sqlite DB and put some flag in the table you store the quotes, so you would know in what activity show up.

Comment: @PiyushGupta "You must use ListView". No. It is probably a better idea here but it isn't absolutely necessary.

Comment: and you can pass your quotes with Intent extras from activities to activities

Comment: Sorry guys, this is my first attempt at an app. I apologize for missing information. The problem is that the text does not become clickable in Einstein class

Answer (score 1):

When you click on your item, simply define an `Intent`, put the needed data inside it and start the second activity, where you'll be able to get the passed data.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  final Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);
  myIntent.putExtra("myquote", "This is the quote I want to pass!");
  startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Now, once in your second `Activity`, simply recover that data:

```
final Intent passedIntent = getIntent();
final String passedQuote = passedIntent.getStringExtra("myquote");
final TextView quotesView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
quotesView.setText(passedQuote);
```